# Improve performance by removing cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

This script is taking hours to execute, is there any way to remove cursor and still iterate over the table on primary key `responseId` ?

```
DECLARE ResponseCursor CURSOR
FOR
     SELECT responseId FROM ResponseTable

FETCH NEXT FROM ResponseCursor INTO @ResponseId

WHILE @@fetch_Status =0
BEGIN
    --Insert Logic 
    FETCH NEXT FROM ResponseCursor INTO @ResponseId
END

CLOSE ResponseCursor
DEALLOCATE ResponseCursor
```

Thanks.

Comment: It rather depends on **exactly** what that `Insert Logic` is, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Tha answer depends on what kind of logic is implemented inside the cursor loop

Comment: well, as it was said on the comments....it depends completely on what the `insert logic` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are many select statements in insert logic.

So i removed Cursor and inserted using joins that table has 100 columns and nearly 1 lakh rows and it took 2 mins to insert all data.

with cursors it took 18 hours,so using joins its super fast.

Answer (score 1):

Sure... just do insert/select

```
insert into MyOtherTable
SELECT responseId, anotherField, 'static text'
FROM ResponseTable
-- add where clause as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are good that the problem is not the cursor, it's whatever your insert logic is. You should verify that you have enough memory on your machine to be doing this loop, and that you have an index on the table.

Some places to start:

1. How long does it take to run the select statement that the cursor does?
2. How long does it take to do a single iteration of the insert logic?
3. Are you doing an Insert Into or a Insert-Select? Check how long the select takes to run, and check your indexes on that query.

Answer (score 0):

use function and put the lines of your select statements in insert logic at that function that return table of the result and use cross apply to join the function with the select statement of the cursor 
SELECT mytable1.result FROM ResponseTable
cross apply ( select *from function(ResponseTable.responseId) dd
where dd.responseId=ResponseTable.responseId) mytable1

where mytable1.responseId=ResponseTable.responseId